why when doing poetry new it sets python version as 3.9?
My pyenv python version is 3.10.1
The system python version is 3.8
However when I do poetry new poetry-demo I get a pyproject.toml with
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

Why?
Just in case my config is
poetry config --list
cache-dir = "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry"
experimental.new-installer = true
experimental.system-git-client = false
installer.max-workers = null
installer.no-binary = null
installer.parallel = true
virtualenvs.create = true
virtualenvs.in-project = null
virtualenvs.options.always-copy = false
virtualenvs.options.no-pip = false
virtualenvs.options.no-setuptools = false
virtualenvs.options.system-site-packages = false
virtualenvs.path = "{cache-dir}/virtualenvs"  # /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
virtualenvs.prefer-active-python = false
virtualenvs.prompt = "{project_name}-py{python_version}"

EDIT: Turns out a clue to this can be found here: https://medium.com/@jamiekt/select-python-interpreter-in-poetry-d20738a8707c
I am going to write my experiments with this later

Poetry will use the interpreter that was used for installing Poetry itself, when creating new project.
If you want Poetry to respect the current active python e.g. set by pyenv you have to set virtualenvs.prefer-active-python to true:
poetry config virtualenvs.prefer-active-python true

See https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsprefer-active-python-experimental
